# Overfull hbox on title page of tufte-book

Tags: titles, tufte, overleaf

I'm writing a book using LaTeX in Overleaf (pdfLaTeX), using the `tufte-book` document type.  To make my title page, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[notoc,symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Sliiightly Long Title \\ \LARGE With A Subtitle}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

The formatting works fine, but the title ends up with an unsightly black bar in the rendered PDF, as such:

[image: title image]

Checking the warnings, I see that I'm getting `Overfull \hbox (8.42856pt too wide)`.  I can manually set the font size down to `\Huge`, but it's much too small and it just looks bad.  `\HUGE` from `moresize` looks more ok, but I have the title in a running head in the rest of the book and it makes it `\HUGE` there too.  (It also makes the subtitle `\LARGE` in the running head, but I decided I actually kind of like the effect there and so I left it.)

Ultimately, I just want to be rid of that black bar from the overfull `\hbox`.  (Why is it even doing that in this case, I don't think I usually see that when I overfill an `\hbox`?)  Does anyone know a way to do this, preferably one that won't mess up my running head or completely ruin the title formatting?

Comment: You might want to squish the space in the subtitle.

Comment: @Oleg Lobachev If I remove the space from the subtitle, my running head ends up with no space between the title and the subtitle, which is no good.  Also I kind of like how it looks tabbed in like that, although I'm sure it's not really what the `tufte-latex` people would have wanted.

Comment: Please provide a compilable example which demonstrates the problem. So you need `\end{document}` at least but, if headers might be an issue, you need code which produces some headers, too. Otherwise, we don't have anything to work with.

Comment: If you just `\lipsum` in a few pages and end the document you should see the headers, but I'll update it to be runnable when I get back in front of a computer

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you're reporting. I don't get the addition of the black block you show here. I do get an overfull hbox warning, but that doesn't affect the output (except that it is spilling into the margin).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the `draft` option somewhere in your class options? In draft mode, LaTeX marks bad hboxes with blocks in the margin.

Comment: Good to know.  I don't think I do though.  On another note, I just got home and am accessing the same document from a different computer, and the box is gone.  Which is weird, because not only is Overleaf a cloud service, but the box rendered out in the PDF when I generated and downloaded it on my other computer...  I'm starting to think I may have just caught some weird, transient bug.

Comment: Still better to eliminate the bad box. More importantly, I definitely wouldn't handle the subtitle that way. If you want a subtitle, make a command to handle it. (Weird that the class provides nothing for this, even though the examples of Tufte's books include some with subtitles.)

Comment: I DID HAVE THE DRAFT OPTION SET!  I just forgot where it was set in the new Overleaf v2 interface.  For anyone from the internet looking for a "why" answer to this question, this is why.  For reference, `draft` is now set in Overleaf v2 in a dropdown menu next to the "Recompile" button, not in the document setting menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I cannot reproduce the issue in the question when I add `\end{document}` to complete the code. I get an overfull `\hbox` warning, but no grey or black block appears in the output. The only thing I know of which might cause this is if you are using the `draft` option, since LaTeX indicates the whereabouts of bad `\hbox`es visually with blocks in the margin.*
>
> *So my answer attempts to eliminate the warning. Since I cannot reproduce the block in the output, I cannot diagnose its cause or attempt to resolve the problem. Nor, therefore, can I say whether eliminating the bad box will eliminate the block. It does, however, eliminate the warning.*
>
> ## *Caveat emptor*

I would consider doing something like the following:

- adjust the use of letter-spacing for the title so that the caps here are not quite as spaced out and `\allcaps` would give you (below, I use 150 rather than 200, but you will need to adjust as desired);

  ```
  \newcommand{\titleallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[150]{#1}}% adjust this as appropriate
  ```

  ```
  \fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\titleallcapsspacing{\MakeTextUppercase{\thanklesstitle}}}%
  ```
- create a new macro `\subtitle`, based on the class's `\title` for a subtitle;

  ```
  \newcommand\@subtitle{}
  \newcommand\plainsubtitle{}
  \newif\if@subtitle
  \newcommand{\subtitle}[2][]{%
    \@subtitletrue
    \gdef\@subtitle{#2}%
    \begingroup
      % TODO store contents of \thanks command
      \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents
      \protected@xdef\thanklesssubtitle{#2}%
    \endgroup
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{\thanklesstitle}}% use thankless subtitle
    {\renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{#1}}% use provided plain-text subtitle
  }
  ```
- customise `\maketitlepage` to use the `\subtitle`;

  ```
  \if@subtitle
    \smallskip\par
    \LARGE\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesssubtitle}}%
  \fi
  ```
- adapt, if appropriate, the definitions of headers, footers or whatever to incorporate `\plainsubtitle` (not shown below as I don't know what you have or haven't got or what you do or don't want here, but, obviously, you can use `\LARGE` or something if you really want to, though it seems odd to have the subtitle larger than the title - or maybe I've misunderstood what you've got).

Then, you can write something like

```
\title{Sliiightly Long Title}
\subtitle{With A Subtitle}
```

```
\maketitle
```

to produce the following result, with no bad boxes.

[image: only good boxes here]

Code:

```
\documentclass[notoc,symmetric,british]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\titleallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[150]{#1}}% adjust this as appropriate
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}[0]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  {%
    \sffamily
    \begin{fullwidth}%
      \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
      \vspace{11.5pc}%
      \fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\titleallcapsspacing{\MakeTextUppercase{\thanklesstitle}}}%
      \if@subtitle
      \smallskip\par
      \LARGE\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesssubtitle}}%
      \fi
      \vfill
      \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}%
    \end{fullwidth}%
  }
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \clearpage
}
\newcommand\@subtitle{}
\newcommand\plainsubtitle{}
\newif\if@subtitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[2][]{%
  \@subtitletrue
  \gdef\@subtitle{#2}%
  \begingroup
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents
    \protected@xdef\thanklesssubtitle{#2}%
  \endgroup
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
  {\renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{\thanklesstitle}}% use thankless subtitle
  {\renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{#1}}% use provided plain-text subtitle
}
\makeatother
\title{Sliiightly Long Title}
\subtitle{With A Subtitle}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

An alternative would be to use the `changepage` package (which is being loaded by the class already) to adjust the margins  in `\maketitlepage`.

Another option would be to just use `\includepdf{}` and generate the title page separately, doing away with `\maketitle` altogether. There's no particular reason not to do this. If you just need minor adjustments, that's one thing, but, if you need more radical changes, a separate file may be the way to go. Since the title page is basically one-off, the usual disadvantages of manually specifying the formatting don't apply.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a thorough and detailed answer!  I've implemented your custom commands and they work like a charm, no more weirdness and it did away with a few other errors at the same time!  I've credited and thanked you in my source code too.

Comment: @realityChemist I often use subtitles. I tend to use `titling` with `article` or `book`, which makes it a bit easier. But the idea is the same in terms of providing `\subtitle` and saving the result in case needed later. Glad it helps. (& thanks for the credit!)